# Execute shell command in Python: 'Bad substitution'

Tags: python, shell

I would like to batch rename files in several directories

Executing `for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" "${file::19}.jpg";done` does it in one directory.

Now I'd like to loop over several like this.

```
import os
folder = ['/dir_1','/dir_2']

for dir_ in folder:
    print(dir_)
    os.chdir(dir_)
    os.system('for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" "${file::19}.jpg";done')
```

However, I get the error `sh: 1: Bad substitution`

Could someone show me how to do this?

Comment: What shell are you using in the single-directory case? Is that the same as your default shell? What does `/bin/sh` point to?

Comment: Are you simply typing `for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" "${file::19}.jpg";done` in the terminal and press Enter to run it?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter expansion is called `Substring Expansion` and is Bash
extension.  It works when you're typing it in command line because you
use Bash as your interactive shell but might not work when you use
`os.system` because it uses `/bin/sh` which might not be Bash but some
smaller POSIX-compliant shell such as `dash`.  You have to use `awk`
to do what you want as described
[here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.24.7Bfoo:3.5B:1.5D.7D)
like that:

```
os.system('for file in *.jpg; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | awk  \'{ string=substr($0, 0, 19); print string; }\')".jpg; done')
```